# My IDA have 2 different address for same code How to change it

Tags: ida, disassembly, address, windows-10, cheat-engine

[image]

I am a novice for use ida pro and I do not know I change some settings that are maked left analyse address wrong.How I fix it?Thanks

Comment: What is on the left and what is on the right?

Comment: You need to tell us how you got the left and the right IDA screenshots. Did you load an EXE file? Did you attach using the built-in debugger? Did you set special flags while loading? Is it the same database file?

Answer (score 0):

That does not appear to be the same binary; they appear to be different, but closely-related versions of the same program. On the right, the instruction at address `0x1417DDCE1` is followed by another instruction at address `0x1417DDCE8`. On the left, the instruction at address `0x1417DDCE1` is followed by another instruction at address `0x1417DDCE5`. (I.e., the last nibble on the left is `5` and the last nibble on the right is `8`.)

Comment: No it is a same dump file.Left's address are analyse wrong.Thank you for your reply